# SparkSubmit doesn't proceed

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I am submitting a `Spark-scala` job. The `hdfs` seems running fine, and I see

```
$jps
1553 NameNode
1649 DataNode
1410 NodeManager
1764 SecondaryNameNode
1908 SparkSubmit
1975 Jps
1306 ResourceManager
```

However, the submitted job doesn't proceed further than the following and it appears as if it is hanged. Does anyone know what's happening or how should I be debugging? I am a novice to most of this technology and feeling at lost :(.

Thanks in advance, Nikhil

[spark-job-log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Qo7T53Jf-rVAThTOHaR4Njkk6jHlE9EXjwPtte0gjko&authuser=0)

Comment: what mode you run (cluster / client)? what scheduling mode (fifo / fair)? can you provide web ui info (if available)? it is standalone? have you tested simple jobs like word count (mb problem in a job)?